# how to display rating value that is stored in database as number of stars

Tags: android, rating

i have a google map app where users can rate on the restaurant they select via marker i stored that rating value in sq lite database and when they click on view rating button i display the name and rating value as string in the scrollview.
Now i want to show that rating value as stars i.e the way the user enters. 
[image: this is how i want to display when view rating is clicked]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="Rate me"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/rateme"
    android:layout_weight="0.00" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Restaurent Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_weight="0.00" />
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="2.0"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/place"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"

    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/rate"
    android:layout_weight="0.00" />

<Button
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:onClick="insert"/>

<Button
    android:text="view Rating"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewrate"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:onClick="display"/>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rat"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.07" />
        />




    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use a `RatingBar` for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you can use `RatingBar`. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html).

**In your layout `XML`:**

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    android:rating="2.0" />
```

**In your `Activity`:**

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);


Float rating = 3.0; // 3.0 is from your database

// To show rating on RatingBar
ratingBar.setRating(rating);
```

**UPDATE:**

To get `rating` from `RatingBar`:

```
Float rating = ratingBar.getRating();

// Show rating on TextView
textView.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(rating));
```

**To get output as like your attached image:**

**#** If the `number` of `Restaurant` fixed. (For example:  `10`):

1. You should add 10 `RatingBar` and 10 `TextView` in your layout `XML`.
2. Use different `id` for RatingBar`(rb1, rb2, rb3.....)` and TextView`(tv1, tv2, tv3.....)`.
3. Get `rating` values from `database`:

   ```
      Float rating1 = 1.0;    
      Float rating2 = 1.0;    
      Float rating3 = 3.0;   
      .............    
      .......................
   ```
4. Set `rating` values to `RatingBar` and `TextView`

   ```
      rb1.setRating(rating1);
      rb2.setRating(rating2);
      rb3.setRating(rating3);
      ................
      ......................

      tv1.setText("Restaurant One" + String.valueOf(rating1));
      tv2.setText("Restaurant Two" + String.valueOf(rating2));
      tv3.setText("Restaurant Three" + String.valueOf(rating3));
      ................
      .......................
   ```

**#** If the `number` of `Restaurant` variable:

1. You should use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.
2. Use an `ArrayList` to store each restaurant data (`name` and `rating`) that you get from `Google Map`.
3. Create a custom `Adapter` to populate each restaurant `data` on row item `view` on `ListView`/`RecyclerView`. Here row item view is a XML containing a `RatingBar` and `TextView`.
4. Pass the restaurant `ArrayList` to `Adapter`
5. Finally, from Adapter's `getView()` or `onBindViewHolder()` get the restaurant `name` and `rating` from `ArrayList` for each `position` and show on `TextView` and `RatingBar`.

Here are some good Tutorials:

1. [Implementation of RatingBar](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/)
2. [Android ListView with Custom Adapter](http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)
3. [Android RecyclerView with Custom Adapter](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/09/android-recyclerview-tutorial.html)

Hope this will help~

Comment: i followed the same tutorial to get rating from user now my question is how to show that in a text view i.e corresponding restaurent name and rating together. When view rating is clicked it shows all the data in database

Comment: no it will show rating value as numbers i want to show it as like stars

Comment: To show rating on RatingBar you should use   ratingBar.setRating(rating); I have already mentioned in my answer

Comment: ya that show only the rating that is inserted at now. i want to show all the rating value in database as like the image

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try this and let me know the result.

Comment: sorry i cant define the number of restaurents as it is shown in the google map by recognising our current location

Comment: Use ListView or RecyclerView. I have updated my answer. hope section # "If the number of Restaurant variable:"  will help

Comment: i helped completed the project thaks

Comment: happy to know that....If my answer seems useful please mark this as accepted answer and also give an upvote. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Go to my answer and see left dise. There is already 3 votes. Just press on UP-ARROW  to give an up-vote and click on below TICK mark to accept my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: if we set the rating bar with the value that we have stored, will it still be clickable? Or will the manual setting make it not clickable?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Float rating = Float.parseFloat(stringFromDatabase);
mRateBar.setRating(rating);

textView.setText("Rating: " + stringFromDatabase);
```

Comment: ya it works  but how to show that in a text view i.e corresponding restaurent name and rating together. When view rating is clicked it shows all the data in database

Comment: Can you post some image or something how you want it to be.

Comment: posted image for reference

Comment: when i add this it gives only the first data of my database